# Anchor idl upgrade triggers: require_gte expression was violated

Tags: anchor

i had to recompile anchor to print the error (is there away to stream idl write logs during `anchor idl upgrade|install`?)

```
> ../anchor/target/debug/anchor idl upgrade brdgwnNUvW8rGAVzRrpiQiRv8dGBVvrJW79UB61sa16 --filepath target/idl/bridge.json --provider.wallet ~/.config/solana/id.json --provider.cluster mainnet
Idl buffer created: G3HXRvUV88oBZnWbE2U9FH9yHMAGJ9ydqM8CMPPqkHvn
e 
$Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x9ca", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, Custom(2506))), logs: Some(["Program brdgwnNUvW8rGAVzRrpiQiRv8dGBVvrJW79UB61sa16 invoke [1]", "Program log: Instruction: IdlSetBuffer", "Program log: AnchorError thrown in programs/bridge/src/lib.rs:16. Error Code: RequireGteViolated. Error Number: 2506. Error Message: A require_gte expression was violated.", "Program log: Left: 1272", "Program log: Right: 2763", "Program brdgwnNUvW8rGAVzRrpiQiRv8dGBVvrJW79UB61sa16 consumed 8534 of 200000 compute units", "Program brdgwnNUvW8rGAVzRrpiQiRv8dGBVvrJW79UB61sa16 failed: custom program error: 0x9ca"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) }
```